# Difference between Strings

Tags: java, string

Is there a method to compare two `String` values like `.compareTo` but that returns the number of letters that aren't the same?

Example:

```
"SomeString".anotherCompareTo("SomeStrng") -> 1
"SomeString".anotherCompareTo("SmeStrng") -> 2
"SomeString".anotherCompareTo("SomeStrong") -> 1
```

I can't find anything. I tried to convert it to charArrays and write a method myself but failed. If this is not possible, maybe there's a method that compares two strings with the same length that returns the number of "mistakes"?

Comment: The second one should be "2", right?

Comment: So you basically want the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? I don't think that's built in to Java but it's relatively easy to implement, lots of examples out there.

Comment: What would (for example) `"acda".anotherCompareTo("bae")` be?

Comment: 0 since order means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Commons has a method to diff Strings

[StringUtils.difference(String str1, String str2)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#difference(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

that you can use to create a method that returns the number of differences very easily.

**Edit**:

Infact it already exists:

[StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(String str1, String str2)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Java's `String.replaceAll()` seems to do what you're wanting.  The first parameter being a regex pattern, so you're asking to replace all characters in the pattern with an empty string leaving the characters that don't match the pattern.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "SomeString";
    String s2 = "SomeStrng";
    String s3 = "SmeStrng";
    String s4 = "SomeStrong";

    String result = s1.replaceAll("[" + s2 + "]", "");
    System.out.println(result + ": " + result.length());

    result = s1.replaceAll("[" + s3 + "]", "");
    System.out.println(result + ": " + result.length());

    result = s1.replaceAll("[" + s4 + "]", "");
    System.out.println(result + ": " + result.length());
}
```

Results:

```
i: 1
oi: 2
i: 1
```